# How do I get started with electronics/hardware?

Tags: arduino, books

I'm a programmer and mathematician by profession, and I would like to get started in electronics/hardware. I have an Arduino, and I've written some basic programs in it (alarm clock with LCD and speaker, etc.), but I would like to learn more about the actual electronics. What books/tutorials are good for this? I don't mind mathematics (esp. calculus since that I would guess is used a lot in EE). In fact, something with good mathematical treatment is welcomed, but I don't want to shy away from intuitive explanations either. Something in the middle would be good. My knowledge right now is:

1. How a resistor works
2. How a capacitor works

and NOTHING ELSE.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Art_of_Electronics

Answer (score 4):

Here is a good [site](http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/) I got shown. Good for explanations of different theories.

Answer (score 1):

To repeat a recommendation I've just made in another thread, I find [Practical Electronics for Inventors](http://www.mhprofessional.com/product.php?isbn=0071452818) to be very clear and accessible.

Answer (score 1):

An excellent site here http://www.doctronics.co.uk/design.htm  - very useful for understanding things like voltage dividers and how analogue sensors work and how to use their output in the Arduino. It's written in a very practical context with example circuits.

When you have a bit of knowledge start trying to understand the datasheets and schematics for linear devices like 741 op amps and 555 timers. This will really help you start to put electronic concepts together.